# ¿Porqué al bloquear un Modal con blockUI me permite entrar textos?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy usando la libreria http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js y los modales de bootstrap3. No comprendo porque cuando bloqueo un elemento en particular en mi caso el modal, sigue permitiendo al usuario desplazarce por los controles usando la tecla Tab, y modificarlos a su antojo. No es problema de la versión porque he usado varias versiones del blockui y sigue igual. Estoy usando jquery 1.10.*

Este es la parte de mi código donde bloqueo el elemento:

```
$('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    $('div.modal-content:first', '#editModal').block({
        message: null, overlayCSS: {
            backgroundColor: '#ccc',
            opacity: 0.1,
            cursor: 'wait'
        }
    });
```

Comment: He revisado el z-index, le puse 5 al del block porque el del modal es 1025, en mi caso yo bloqueaba .modal.modal-content y ese no tenia z-index, cambie a bloquear .modal que tenia z-index que fue el que indique arriba, sin embargo sigue igual. Estableci al .modal-content un z-index como me explicastes que fuera mayor que el del block pero sigue haciendo lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente el z-index no sea el adecuado y los elementos queden encima de la capa block.

Igual hay otra alternativa con la propiedad block, en ella puedes bloquear solamente el modal que necesitas.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#blockButton').click(function() { 
            $('div.test').block({ message: null }); 
        }); 

        $('#blockButton2').click(function() { 
            $('div.test').block({ 
                message: '<h1>Processing</h1>', 
                css: { border: '3px solid #a00' } 
            }); 
        }); 

        $('#unblockButton').click(function() { 
            $('div.test').unblock(); 
        }); 

        $('a.test').click(function() { 
            alert('link clicked'); 
            return false; 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

**EDIT**
Malinterprete. Las funcione de **block()** y **unblock()** bloquean únicamente el elemento y su contenido asignado. Si quieres hacerlo con la pantalla completa tendrás que llamar a

```
$.blockUI({ message: mensajes."Procesando..."});
$.unblockUI();
```

Comment: Mira estuve revisando y cuando llamo a $.blockUi si me funciona, no me deja entrar valores en el modal, pero no quiero bloquear la pagina completa sino solo el contenido del modal y con $('selector').block no funciona así, cual es tu consejo????

Comment: con **$('#modal').block({ message: null });** debe de ser suficiente para bloquear, lanza algún error la consola?

Comment: He estado jugando con el z-index de ambos tanto del .modal como el del .blockUI y nada de nada, ya los he puesto el primero mayor que el segundo y nada, y viceversa también.

Comment: No lanza ningún error. Lo que sucede es que solo veo el efecto de escala de grises que el crea, no me deja dar click adentro del modal pero si puedo usar el teclado a mi antojo en cualquier campo dentro del mismo

Comment: usa la configuracion de **bindEvents: false,** en el block. Por default es falso pero al ponerla en true te permite editar. Sí esto no funciona tendrás que cambiar el selector, en el selector solo agrega el id del modal.

Comment: A ver no me di a entender bien, sorry. **YO QUIERO QUE NO SE PUEDA EDITAR**, ya revise y tengo tanto **bindEvents** como **contrainTabKey** en **true** en el js del blockui, no obstante lo establezo en las opciones de la llamada del blockui y me sigue permitiendo editar

Comment: Entonces cambia el selector $("'div.modal-content:first', '#editModal'") porque este no está bloqueando adecuadamente. Al block asiganle solamente el id del modal para no confundirlo como $(''#editModal').block({   message: null,    });

Comment: Ya lo he puesto de mil maneras, inclusive asi: $('#editModal').block({ message: null }); y nada